# best linked list in ruby WITHOUT extending array?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

What is the best way to implement a linked list in Ruby without using/extending the Array class?  This is an implementation that I've used in the past, but it doesn't seem like the best way to go about it:

```
class Node

    attr_accessor :value, :next_node

    def initialize(value = nil)
        @value = value
    end

    def to_s
        @value
    end

end

class SinglyLinkedList

    attr_accessor :head

    def initialize(first_value=nil)
        @head = Node.new(first_value) if first_value
    end

    def add(value)
        #adds a new node to the list, amakes it the new head and links it to the former head
        new_node = Node.new(value)
        new_node.next_node = @head

        @head = new_node
    end

    def remove
        @head = @head.next_node
    end
end
```

Comment: What don't you like about it? (except that it doesn't work)

Comment: Sergio, I pasted in the wrong version of the SLL class.  It should work now.  What I don't like about it is that I don't have a good traversal or "find_node" method.  Any ideas on how to implement that from scratch in an efficient way?

Comment: Find in a linked list is always `O(n)`. Just walk the array.

Comment: Depends on what do you consider "efficient". Accessing a node is O(N).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Although you could "simulate" a linked list and actually use an array on the back end. Then you could use Ruby's array  methods. I don't know what their big-oh is though.

Comment: @screenmutt: then it's cheating and not accomplishing anything. You get worst of both worlds. Since you pretend it's a linked list, you get limited interface. And because it's an array, you don't get O(1) insertions.

Comment: Gotcha.  Well O(n) is fine, but I just wanted see if anyone knew of something better than that.  I think this article pointed out that there may just be nothing fast for SLLs: http://www.sitepoint.com/data-structures-big-o-and-you/

Comment: @sergio Definitely true, it just depends on what he is going to use more often. I would say what he is using now is near optimal.

Comment: @omdel Check out wikipedia [on linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). It doesn't get better than O(n).

Comment: yeah it def. just doesn't get better than O(n), I guess.  thanks, guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across an interesting implementation of linked lists recently (not sure where unfortunatly) where the `Node` class implemented the insert and removal methods.  The following is the `Node` class for a double linked list, but the same principles would apply for single linked list.

```
class Node
  protected
  attr_writer :prev, :next

  public
  attr_reader :value, :prev, :next

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def remove
    @prev.next = @next if @prev
    @next.prev = @prev if @next
    @next = @prev = nil
  end

  def insert_after(node)
    remove

    @next = node.next
    @next.prev = self if @next
    @prev = node
    node.next = self
  end
end
```

I find this implementation interesting because I've found it to be quite versatile.  Nothing more than a `Node` is needed to start building out a list and manipulating it.

```
head = Node.new(1)

middle = Node.new(2)
middle.insert_after(head)

tail = Node.new(3)
tail.insert_after(middle)

middle.remove
```

On top of this implementation you can then build a more advanced API that's pretty easy to understand.  The following is a more complete version of a `LinkedList` or `Deque`.  The list itself subclasses `Node` and links to the head and tail of the list.

```
class ListNode < Node
  protected :remove # prevent incorrect access to Node methods

  def initialize
    @next = @prev = self
  end

  def head
    @next unless @next == self
  end

  def tail
    @prev unless @prev == self
  end

  def add_to_head(node)
    node.insert_after(self)
  end

  def add_to_tail(node)
    node.insert_after(self.prev)
  end

  def each(&block)
    return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?
    node = @next
    while node != self
      yield node
      node = node.next
    end
  end

  def to_a
    each.collect {|node| node.value }
  end
end
```

And here is how it can be used in practice:

```
# create a new list
list = ListNode.new

# add some items to the head or tail
list.add_to_head(Node.new('Hello'))
list.add_to_tail(Node.new('World'))
list.to_a # => ["Hello", "World"]

# remove items from the head
list.head.remove
list.to_a # => ["World"]
list.head == list.tail # => true

# remove items from the tail
list.tail.remove
list.to_a # => []
```

Even better is the `each` method which allows us to use any of the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html) functions to search and iterate through the nodes:

```
list = ListNode.new
list.add_to_head(Node.new(1))
list.add_to_head(Node.new(2))
list.add_to_head(Node.new(3))
list.add_to_head(Node.new(4))

# list each value
list.each {|node| puts node.value }

# select all nodes with values greater than 2
list.each.select {|node| node.value > 2 }

# find the first node with a value of 4
list.each.find {|node| node.value == 4 }
```

Answer (score 11):

I assume you are implementing this for self-teaching, otherwise it doesn't makes any sense. Just use `Array`, that is the list implementation for ruby.

In my opinion, you should write these exercises in C, because the whole point in implementing a linked list is to be closer to the machine and understand better how it works. C is a way better tool for this task, understand how computer works.

This is how a classical linked list is teach on college: `O(n)` to insert, `O(n)` to search, and `O(n)` to delete. Afterwards, most books discuss about improvements on it.

I wrote in in the top of my head, and did no tests on it at all, but this should give you an idea, and hopefully an exercise to correct any bugs you found. (update: @Nitesh found a typo, and fixed it. Hopefully it have some test now).

```
class Node
    attr_accessor :value, :next

    def initialize(value = nil)
        @value = value
    end

    def to_s
        @value
    end
end

class SinglyLinkedList

    attr_accessor :head

    def initialize(first_value=nil)
      @head = Node.new(first_value) if first_value
    end

    def add(value)
      if head.nil?
        head = Node.new(value)
      else
        current_node = @head
        while current_node.next
          current_node = current_node.next
        end
        current_node.next = Node.new(value)
      end
    end

    def find(value)
      current_node = head
      while current_node != nil
        return current_node if current_node.value == value
        current_node = current_node.next
      end
      nil
    end

    def remove(value)
      if head.value == value
        head = head.next
      else
        current_node = head.next
        prev_node = head
        while current_node
          if current_node.value == value
            prev_node.next = current_node.next
            return true
          end
          prev_node = current_node
          current_node = current_node.next
        end
        nil
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks! I like your improvements on this.  I am indeed doing this for self-study and in to make a small, Ruby library of extra data-structures in Ruby for personal use and reference.

Comment: missing '@' for setting member variable in add, remove methods. Would have just edited the answer, but SO doesn't appreciate 2 character edits.